# Django m2m THROUGH extra fields reference in template ++

Tags: django

Ive a problem referencing to my "THROUGH" m2m model extra fields.  I
can reference the linked model (User), but not the extra detail on the
"through-model" (listuser)

My Model definition---
User model is the built in User model Untouched.

```
class joblist(models.Model):
    userdetail = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='userextra')

class userextra(models.Model):
    joblist = models.ForeignKey(joblist)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comments= models.CharField(max_length=16384, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my Template-----

```
{% for row in joblist %}
html here
{% for item in row.userdetail.all  %}
{{item.username}}-"I want to print comments here"
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ive tried `{{item.userextra.comments}}  {{item.comments}} {{item.douser.comments}}`

So I am getting the detail from the "User" model but Im not getting
the extra fields on the userextra model????

Any help appreciated....
N

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need an answer...  I'm new to Python/Django but I was searching for the same thing and your question ranked high in Google when I was searching so thought I'd answer it in case anyone else is searching.

Here's what I was able to find: Rather than iterate over `row.userdetail.all`, try iterating over `row.userextra_set.all`.

```
{% for row in joblist %}
html here
{% for item in row.userextra_set.all %}
{{ item.user.username }} - {{ item.comments }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got more backflip potential in the view than the template.

So, while it's an inelegant solution, I'd suggest querying the through model in the view directly and then using what you get back to temporarily annotate the items in the rows of your joblist appropriately so that you can definitely, cleanly, do row.foo.bar or item.baz.boof, etc, *then* pass that manually annotated set of results into the template.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what you mean, Could you give an example?
I already do some filtering in views, but that doesnt help displaying it in the template.  I dont know how/if to rearrange the Queryset?

Comment: But if I'm iterating through a list of jobs in the template, going back to the view is... awkward.

Comment: You iterate and annotate in the view, then iterate again in the template - you can't go back to the view from the template...